# Cannot disable inputs with respect to id of div through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have different forms inside divs with different ids. What I am doing is that I am using radio buttons to disable their respective divs.

My code isn't working here is what I tried

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.address_type').change(function() {
    if (this.value == '0') {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      $("#add_0_" + id).find("input[class='secondary']").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $("#add_0_" + id).find("input[class='secondary']").prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="/ali_store/order/place" method="POST">
  <div class="collapse in" id="ali_store">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="CJDqNipNtpNavJ9m1fogtUyCThJe2GCS75bI6KJ2">
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="panel-body">
      Address Information
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input type="radio" name="add_type" class="address_type" id="ali_store" value="1" checked />&nbsp;Use This Address
          
          <div id="add_1_ali_store">
            <br /> asd
            <br /> asd,
            <br /> xcv
            <br /> sdf
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input type="radio" name="add_type" class="address_type" id="ali_store" value="0" />&nbsp;Use This Address
          <div id="add_0_ali_store">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">House no.</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_hno" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Street</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_street" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Area</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_area" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">City</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_city" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">State</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_state" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Postal Code</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_postal" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Phone</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_phone" class="secondary form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Mobile</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_mobile" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <div>
        TOTAL: <strong>Rs. 186,145.00 /-</strong>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" formtarget="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" value="Place Order" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<form action="/ali2/order/place" method="POST">
  <div class="collapse in" id="ali2">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="CJDqNipNtpNavJ9m1fogtUyCThJe2GCS75bI6KJ2">

    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="panel-body">
      Address Information
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input type="radio" name="add_type" class="address_type" id="ali2" value="1" checked />&nbsp;Use This Address

          <div id="add_1_ali2">
            <br /> asd
            <br /> asd
            <br /> asd
            <br /> asd
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input type="radio" name="add_type" class="address_type" id="ali2" value="0" />&nbsp;Use This Address
          <div id="add_0_ali2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">House no.</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_hno" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Street</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_street" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Area</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_area" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">City</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_city" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">State</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_state" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Postal Code</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_postal" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Phone</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_phone" class="secondary form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Mobile</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_mobile" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <div>
        TOTAL: <strong>Rs. 1,331.00 /-</strong>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" formtarget="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" value="Place Order" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<form action="/ali3/order/place" method="POST">
  <div class="collapse in" id="ali3">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="CJDqNipNtpNavJ9m1fogtUyCThJe2GCS75bI6KJ2">

    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="panel-body">
      Address Information
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input type="radio" name="add_type" class="address_type" id="ali3" value="1" checked />&nbsp;Use This Address
 
          <div id="add_1_ali3">
            <br /> dsa
            <br /> dsa
            <br /> dsa
            <br /> dsa
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input type="radio" name="add_type" class="address_type" id="ali3" value="0" />&nbsp;Use This Address
          <div id="add_0_ali3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">House no.</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_hno" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Street</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_street" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Area</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_area" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">City</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_city" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">State</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_state" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Postal Code</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_postal" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Phone</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_phone" class="secondary form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4">Mobile</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" name="address_secondary_mobile" class="secondary form-control" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <div>
        TOTAL: <strong>Rs. 1,500.00 /-</strong>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" formtarget="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" value="Place Order" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I want that if I change the radio button and it has value '0' then its input fields get disabled only else enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.address_type').change(function() {
if (this.value == '0') {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $("#add_0_" + id).find("input.secondary").prop("disabled", false);
} else {
  $("#add_0_" + id).find("input.secondary").prop("disabled", true);
}
```

});
});